# Windows Server version and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

Is there a blog / webpage / information (I did not find anything) out there, if it has performance benefits, if I use a newer Windows Server version for my SQL Server?

Example: I run SQL 2016 on a Windows Server 2012. Does it make sense to update this server to Windows Server 2016 or the upcoming Windows Server 2019 beside those out-of-support lifecycle topics? Does it make a difference, if I install a new SQL Server 2019 (if it is out) on Windows Server 2016 or Windows Server 2019?

PS: The only point I found to this topic was that - if I want to use NVDIMMs I should use Windows Server 2016 for better support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There would not be any noticeable performance benefit if you move to higher version of windows server. Normally people move to higher version keeping support in perspective and the *host of new features* they get in newer version of windows. Refer [Compare features in Windows Server versions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/cloud-platform/windows-server-comparison) to see list of new features you get in various versions of Windows Server.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what features you are going to use from SQL end. Per my experience, if you are going to use availability groups, then you should consider Windows 2016 running SQL 2016 rather than on Windows 2012 due to many reasons. I personally have seen performance improvements running SQL 2016 on windows 2016 when compared the baselines I had collected overtime.

Apart from performance, there are many benefits running SQL2016 on windows 2016 specially Quorum changes in this version.please check msdn link for further info.